# Undecorated JFrame maximize always uses primary monitor resolution in OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing

I am having an issue when maximizing an undecorated frame on the secondary (or any non-primary) monitor in OS X. It seems like when maximizing the frame on the second monitor, the bounds of the primary monitor is used and the frame is either resized beyond the screen bounds (if the primary monitor is bigger) or it does not fill the entire screen (if the primary monitor is smaller).

The problem occurs with Java 1.8.0_40 in OS X Yosemite. The problem did not occur when tested in Windows and Linux.

When running the app it looks like this. The grid of numbers was added to be able to see if the frame extends beyond the screen bounds.

[image: Maximize Test]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MaximizeTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaximizeTest frame = new MaximizeTest();
        frame.dispose();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final JPanel mainPanel = new NumberGridPanel();
    private final JButton maximizeButton = new JButton();
    private final JButton closeButton = new JButton();

    public MaximizeTest() {
        initComponents();

        // Added this to be able to drag the frame to other monitors
        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new DragMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        maximizeButton.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        closeButton.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        maximizeButton.setText("Maximize/Minimize");
        maximizeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                int state = getExtendedState();
                if ((state & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) != 0) {
                    setExtendedState(state & ~Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                    setSize(400, 400);
                } else {
                    // Take OS taskbars and dockbars into account
                    Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
                    if (screenInsets.left == 0 && screenInsets.right == 0
                            && screenInsets.top == 0 && screenInsets.bottom == 0) {
                        setMaximizedBounds(null);
                    } else {
                        Rectangle screenBounds = getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
                        Rectangle newBounds = new Rectangle(
                                screenInsets.left,
                                screenInsets.top,
                                screenBounds.width - (screenInsets.left + screenInsets.right),
                                screenBounds.height - (screenInsets.top + screenInsets.bottom));
                        setMaximizedBounds(newBounds);
                    }

                    setExtendedState(state | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        mainPanel.add(maximizeButton, gridBagConstraints);

        closeButton.setText("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        mainPanel.add(closeButton, gridBagConstraints);

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static class NumberGridPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            int gridSize = 30;
            int cols = getWidth() / gridSize;
            int rows = getHeight() / gridSize;
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    g.drawString(Integer.toString((col + row) * gridSize), col * gridSize, row * gridSize + 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        private int previousMouseX;
        private int previousMouseY;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            previousMouseX = e.getXOnScreen();
            previousMouseY = e.getYOnScreen();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int state = getExtendedState();
            if ((state & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == 0) { // if not maximized
                setLocation(
                        e.getXOnScreen() - previousMouseX + getX(), 
                        e.getYOnScreen() - previousMouseY + getY());
                previousMouseX = e.getXOnScreen();
                previousMouseY = e.getYOnScreen();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I haven't been able to find anything about this issue on the web. I'll be grateful if anyone can help me with a fix or workaround for this issue or point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

After further investigation it seems that it is not the resolution of the primary screen that influences the maximized region on the second screen but rather the y-offset of the virtual arrangement of the two screens. If the primary screen is lower that the secondary screen in the virtual arrangement then a gap appears at the top of the secondary screen when maximizing the frame.

Also, after changing the resolution of the primary screen the issue disappeared completely and I wasn't able to reproduce it again even after changing the resolution back to what it was originally and even after a complete OS restart.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when manually selection the `GraphicsConfiguration` of the non-primary display ? E.g. using `GraphicsEnvironment#getScreenDevices()[x]#getDefaultConfiguration()`

Comment: Yes the same problem occurs. The bounds from the `GraphicsConfiguration` of all the screens are correct and `getGraphicsConfiguration()` returns the configuration for the correct screen. Which can only mean that `setMaximizedBounds()` is not working correctly for some reason.

Comment: This seems like it might be a java issue, second screens seem like something that could have been overlooked in the development of the JDK